# Text in TextView generated from mysqlite is pushed off screen LinearLayout

Tags: android

The product details text which is fetched from the mysqlite database is pushed off the screen. I have look at other post with similar questions but none using mysqlite (I do not think this is the problem).

The text is displayed in a fragment opened when an element is clicked in the MainActivity.

I feel I am right using LinearLayout as it is just details about a product with a hint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ProductDescriptionFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Fragment"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductNameFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Product Name: "
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductPriceFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Product Price: "
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductQuantityFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Product Quantity: "
        android:inputType="text" />


    <!-- This is the textView which is being pushed off the scrren -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductDescriptionDetailedFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Product Description: "
        android:inputType="text" />
          
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your width should be `match_parent` . `wrap_content` makes your view as something which can take infinite length. change:

```
    <!-- This is the textView which is being pushed off the scrren -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductDescriptionDetailedFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Product Description: "
        android:inputType="text" />
```

to

```
    <!-- This is the textView which is being pushed off the scrren -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtViewProductDescriptionDetailedFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Product Description: "
        />
```

Comment: This has not worked, is it because I am using a fragment? But I can not see why this would be the problem

Comment: @Liam can you share more info around the problem? where are you trying to use the fragment and what code are you using in the fragment/activity ? the problem with views are usually in either xmls or around the way we access them in activity/fragment

Comment: Yeah no problem

Comment: i don't see a problem in your code. can you share the main activity **xml** file too? and also try running your app once without the description and then with the description textview with the changes i mentioned in the answer above. also if you notice, i removed the `inputType` because that's an attribute for edit text and not the textview

Comment: Thanks it worked I just ran the code without the description and then with the description and it has seemed to work now. Why is this?

Comment: @Liam sometimes the latest changes do not get reflected in the app.  you can  run "clean Project" from the build menu in the top of  android studio before installing the app again, it will then reflect all the changes. or sometimes just uninstalling the app manually before installing the app from studio also starts reflecting the latest changes. just the weird quirks of any kind of IDE used for development